# Rails 3: Order a query that uses a has_many and belongs_to association in one query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, belongs-to, arel

In my Rails db scheme there is the following structure:

tasks has many jobs
jobs belongs to one category

What I want to achieve is to load all tasks with all the associated jobs ordered by their category. So the result should look something like this:

task1
  job1 -> category1
  job3 -> category2
  job2 -> category3

task3
  job5 -> category1
  job9 -> category2
  job4 -> category3

Note: the ordering of the categories is not their ID, it is a column.

Right now the only working solution is to order the jobs in Ruby and not SQL, which is pretty bad. I just stumpled on the :finder_sql option in the has_many association, but I am not sure if that's the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would generate the correct sql, but Im not sure ActiveRecord wil preserve the order in the association:

`Task.find(:all, :include => {:job => :category }, :order =>'tasks.id, categories.column')`

Comment: like I wrote, the category_id does **not** indicate the ordering. That's the real problem.

Comment: Thank you! The :include => {:job => :category} did the trick. I didn't know that include is so powerful.